Terraform Storage Bucket Encryption is not working
I have a terraform script that creates a storage bucket and adds encryption to it. I already have a KMS key rings and the key created. I also have a service account with the following roles
"CLOUD KMS ADMIN" "Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter"
I am getting the following error
googleapi: Error 403: Permission denied on Cloud KMS key. Please ensure that your Cloud Storage service account has been authorized to use this key., forbidden
│ 
│   with module.storage-bucket.google_storage_bucket.storage-bucket,
│   on ../../modules/storage/main.tf line 1, in resource "google_storage_bucket" "storage-bucket":
│    1: resource "google_storage_bucket" "storage-bucket" {


I tried adding the admin role to the service account it did not work. This is my storage script
resource "google_storage_bucket" "storage-bucket" {
    name = var.storage_bucket
    location = var.project_region
    project = var.project_id

    versioning {
      enabled = true
    }

    uniform_bucket_level_access = true
    public_access_prevention = var.access_prevention_policy

    lifecycle_rule {
      action {
        type = var.change_storage_type
        storage_class = var.nearline_storage_class
      }
      condition {
        age = var.nearline_storage_age

      }

    }

    lifecycle_rule {
      action {
        type = var.change_storage_type
        storage_class = var.coldline_storage_class
      }
      condition {
        age = var.coldline_storage_age
        
      }

    }

    lifecycle_rule {
      action {
        type = var.change_storage_type
        storage_class = var.archive_storage_class
      }
      condition {
        age = var.archive_storage_age
        
      }

    }

    lifecycle_rule {
      action {
        type = var.delete
      }
      condition {
        age = var.delete_age
        
      }

    }
    
    logging {
      log_bucket = var.storage_bucket
      log_object_prefix = var.log_object_prefix
    }

    labels = {
      environment = var.environment
    }  

    encryption {
      default_kms_key_name = var.key_name
    }
}


I did verify that my resource name for the KMS key is correct and it in the appropriate region.
Can someone let me know where either went wrong.
